# Update nested values based on a condition using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to update a value in an array in a nested object structure using Ramda.

I want to update the value prop of the object in `C` with the name `blah`

```
const o = {
  A: {
    B: {
      C: [
        {name: 'blah', value: 'blah'},
        {name: 'vtha', value: 'blah'},
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've been plying with lenses, but it seems quite verbose and I figure I am doing it wrong.

Ideally, I would love something that returns a new object.

```
const res = fn(o)


{
  A: {
    B: {
      C: [
        {name: 'blah', value: 'vtha'}
        {name: 'vtha', value: 'blah'},
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's why proper types are more important than proper algorithms: you chose the weird structure, no wondering to modify it you need weird code.

Comment: It's data being returned from an api call. I can split this into sub elements and stitch it back together, but surely updating a value inside a structure is something that can be done in a reasonable way?

Comment: Yep, do it in imperative way: `const obj = o.A.B.C.find(nested => nested.name === 'blah');
if (obj !== undefined) {
    obj.value = 'vtha';
}` it's easy to read and maintain. If necessary - wrap it in a function to look "functional".

Comment: @zerkms _That's why proper types are more important than proper algorithms._ Indeed and additionally: Proper types naturally lead to proper algorithms. We need to talk more about types in Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it in immutable way it would be like

```
const fn = over(
  R.lensPath(['A', 'B', 'C']),
  R.map(
    o => o.name === 'blah' ? R.assoc('value', 'vtha', o): o
  )
)
```

[Demo.](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20o%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20A%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20B%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20C%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27blah%27%2C%20value%3A%20%27blah%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27vtha%27%2C%20value%3A%20%27blah%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20fn%20%3D%20over%28%0A%20%20R.lensPath%28%5B%27A%27%2C%20%27B%27%2C%20%27C%27%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20R.map%28%0A%20%20%20%20o%20%3D%3E%20o.name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27blah%27%20%3F%20R.assoc%28%27value%27%2C%20%27vtha%27%2C%20o%29%3A%20o%0A%20%20%29%0A%29%0A%0Afn%28o%29%0A%0A)

If you want to avoid manually defining functions by all means you could replace mapped function with

```
R.ifElse(
  R.propEq('name', 'blah'),
  R.assoc('value', 'blah'),
  R.identity
)
```

But imho ternary operator looks more readable here.

Comment: [`when`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#when) is a neat shorthand when the else-function is `identity`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using filter and where, i wrote an example below.

```
const o = {
  A: {
    B: {
      C: [
        {name: 'blah', value: 'blah'},
        {name: 'vtha', value: 'blah'},
      ]
    }
  }
};

var pred = R.filter(R.where({name: R.contains('blah')}));

pred(o.A.B.C);
```

Comment: `var pred = a => a.filter(o => o.name === 'blah');`. Easier to read, faster, consumes less memory, vanilla JS, does the same.

Answer (score 0):

To update the array in the object we need the path to the array. Then we can update the result with a lens and a helper function `adjustIfSatisfies`

```js
const { propEq, identity, over, assoc, curry, lensPath, map, ifElse } = R
const o = {
  A: {
    B: {
      C: [
        {name: 'blah', value: 'blah'},
        {name: 'vtha', value: 'blah'},
      ]
    }
  }
}

const adjustIfSatisfies = curry(
  (pred, updateFn, samples) => {
    return map(ifElse(pred, updateFn, identity), samples)
  }
)

const result = over(
  lensPath(['A', 'B', 'C']), 
  adjustIfSatisfies(
    propEq('name', 'blah'), 
    assoc('value', 'vtha')
  ),
  o
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```